# Is it impossible to build with MAVEN instead of gradle in ANDROID STUDIO?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I want to build mobile application with `maven`, not `gradle`.

but android studio ide support `gradle` as a default build tool.

I can't find how to switch to the `maven`.

Is it impossible?

Comment: Android Studio doesn't support Maven yet. So I recommend you to use gradle, or use IntelliJ, that supports Maven.

Comment: I think I should use maven... actually I wanted to develop an app with eclipse but now it's not supported. so I changed IDE but cannot use the maven.. the problem is I'm developing an android app in android studio and java application in eclipse at the same time.

Comment: Well, nothing stops you to use Android Studio but build your app manually by terminal.

Comment: *Why* Maven? Gradle is the official build system.

Comment: @W.Cointreau what do you mean with "eclipse is not supported". I am currently using its latest version (Luna 4.4.2) with the ADT plugin for android app(s)

Comment: @stan0 I heard it isn't supported now, but if it's possible there's no reason to use android studio.... thanks. I'm trying. :)

Comment: thank you, I finally decided to use gradle.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you like gradle?

Comment: gradle doesn't work perfectly for me, such as it doesn't support global maven repo setting.

Comment: Because Gradle is an ugly mess of messes. There's no way to set a single proxy repository system-wide like there is with Maven, the .gradle files are outright painful to read, and it requires yet another JVM runtime language. It allows arbitrary code to be run during the build that may well be unreproducible or impossible to properly audit for changes.

It takes all the misguided-and-ripe-for-abuse-in-hindsight features of Ant and brings them back because somebody forgot they were bad ideas.

Comment: Maven is for developers who just want to write Java. Gradle is for micromanagers who are obsessed with customizing everything.

Comment: I'm also here to say Gradle is a mess and product of unthoroughly thinking. There are two many syntaxes for "the-same-but-not-quite" thing. I've got headache and wasted a lot of time with it. Never had these problems with Maven.